# How to set collections in Mockito.mvc.perform(get("/demo").param("setVal", Set<String>)

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, junit4

I am writing JUnit Test case using Mockit.mvc and I have an API which as "Set <String" as request param and I want to test this API.

> Example Api

```
@GetMapping("/api")    
public ResponseEntity<?> getValue(@RequestParam String name, @RequestParam Set<String recptNum){.....}
```

> UT Snippet

```
Set<String> recNum = new HashMap<>();
recNum.add("someVal");
mvc.perform(get("/api").param("name", "Ram").param("recptNum", recNum).andExpect(status.isOk());
```

Here I tried various ways to test the API but I am always not getting value in recNum. Can anyone please let me know, how to pass the Set value in param or is there anyway I can test it? Feel free to ask me, if you want some more information.

> Below are the codes which I have tried

```
1. mvc.perform(get("/api").param("name", "Ram").param("recptNum","val1", "val2").andExpect(status.isOk());
2. Set<String> recNum = new HashMap<>();
   recNum.add("someVal");
   mvc.perform(get("/api").param("name", "Ram").param("recptNum", String.valueOf(recNum)).andExpect(status.isOk());
3. Set<String> recNum = new HashMap<>();
   recNum.add("someVal");
   mvc.perform(get("/api").param("name", "Ram").requestAttr("recptNum", recNum).andExpect(status.isOk());
4. mvc.perform(get("/api").param("name", "Ram").param("recptNum","val1, val2").andExpect(status.isOk());
5. mvc.perform(get("/api").param("name", "Ram").param("recptNum","val1").param("recptNum", "val2").andExpect(status.isOk());
```

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: You don't. Either add the same parameter multiple times, or create a comma separated list and pass that in as the value.

Comment: Hi @M.Deinum, I actually tried that way, but I am not getting values unfortunately.

Comment: Well your parameter is named `recptNum` and not `receiptNumbers`, those don't match.

Comment: @M.Deinum, I am sorry My mistake it was typo when I was typing it on Stackoverflow but In actual code I am setting it correct.

Comment: THen what did you try? Either adding it as multiple arguments, or a comma separated list should work.

Comment: To pass as Set/List of values use the same param name multiple times.

mockMvc.perform(
   MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/api")
     .param("name", "Manjunath")
     .param("recptNum", "Test1")
     .param("recptNum", "Test2")
     .param("recptNum", "Test3")
     .param("recptNum", "Test4")
  )
  .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());

Comment: @M.Deinum I have updated the question. You may see there what I have tried so far. Some I forgetting to mention as I will remember, I will update it.

Comment: 1 should work, 2 and 3 will not work. You haven't tried a comma separated list `recptNum, "val1,val2,val3"`. There is something there, as when you omit the values, you would get a status 400 back (as parameters are required by default).

Comment: @M.Deinum I tried what you said but still no progress.

Comment: Hi @ManjunathHM, I tried your ways as well but still I am not getting values.

Comment: Please add your whole test and controller. These snippets don't even align, provide a full working sample.

Comment: @M.Deinum it’s working API which I have provided sir. It’s simple SpringBoot application with Mockito. How can I put my whole workspace here?

Comment: It isn't, It is only a method signature and a part of a test. So it isn't a full API nor something we can test.